# What percentage of down votes are users responsible for?

Tags: beginner, sql, stackexchange, t-sql

I put together [this simple query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/429233/what-percentage-of-down-votes-are-users-responsible-for) to calculate the percentage of downvotes each user is responsible for and displaying them in order of downvote percentage. It's generating the desired results, but I am uncertain about style and best practices.

```
WITH DownVoteCount AS (
SELECT DownVoteCount = CAST(SUM(DownVotes) AS float)
FROM Users
), DownVoteWeight AS (
SELECT DisplayName, UpVotes, DownVoteWeight = ROUND(DownVotes / (SELECT DownVoteCount from DownVoteCount) * 100, 4)
FROM Users
Where Users.DownVotes > 0
)

SELECT DisplayName, DownVoteWeight
FROM DownVoteWeight

ORDER BY DownVoteWeight DESC, UpVotes
```

I read about the capitalization of keywords, and decided it would be useful [in case of working with SQL inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6880189/4957418), where syntax highlighting wouldn't be available.

Comment: It would be more interesting to see these numbers side by side with the percentage of total votes a user is responsible for.

Comment: @RubberDuck [done](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/429233/what-percentage-of-down-votes-are-users-responsible-for)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/429907/what-percentage-of-down-votes-are-users-responsible-for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### SQL casing shouldn't matter (much)

Every SQL developer I know writes their queries a bit differently. Case/style shouldn't matter much or at all, if the SQL code works but it's a bit sloppy. Favor substance over style. For example, these 3 queries are identical, as far as the database engine cares:

```
/* These are all exactly the same in SQL: */
SELECT FOO, BAR FROM TEST;
Select Foo, Bar From Test;
select foo, bar from test;
```

---

#### That being said...

...there are a few things we could probably improve in your own query...

Some indentation would feel nice, especially in the subqueries/CTEs. Some indentation will make your code much easier to read:

```
WITH foo AS (
    ... 
),
bar AS (
    ... 
)
--etc
```

---

#### Lines breaks

Line breaks...also feel nice, especially for breaking down business logic, which `DownVoteWeight` is (for instance), where it can be broken down into meaningful functions/operations. This one might deserve a bit more documentation.

```
SELECT 
    DisplayName, 
    UpVotes, 
    DownVoteWeight = ROUND(
        DownVotes / (SELECT DownVoteCount from DownVoteCount) * 100, 4
    )
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't do any indentation since SEDE automatically trims it when you write certain keywords/characters. The linebroken business logic looks a lot better, thanks!